# www-data User cannot access mounted partition

Tags: partitioning, permissions, mount, hard-drive, fstab

On my local dev machine my nginx server runs as user www-data. I have a separate 3TB HDD which stores my local websites. The HDD is mounted automatically on Ubuntu 16.04 startup. I can access my files properly with my own user, but when I su www-data and try to access the files that way I get a permissions error when accessing anything mounted in the /media/ folder.

How can I allow www-data to access this hard drive?

Details: BLKID (last HDD)

```
sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="BB84-E577" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="d62d7f99-f050-4411-8e57-0030bbd73635"
/dev/sda2: UUID="aba7016b-3277-416b-9243-fc10f1752b12" TYPE="ext2" PARTUUID="d567afcf-1f63-4f53-a8a9-d61c619f9493"
/dev/sda3: UUID="r3Gnc3-zpe7-m81D-dBde-ShtM-6z0j-FZhaIG" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="d4ffe4c2-0c4e-45bd-83fe-3d12d5b4a74b"
/dev/sdb1: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="ff6c7bf2-9ffa-4d27-aebd-8f4f9569b985"
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: UUID="fd4ff318-8e5c-489e-a17c-08a6c02f7919" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: UUID="86e3d28e-3c13-4e5d-a8c1-ad56778355e7" TYPE="swap"
/dev/sdb2: LABEL="data" UUID="53c5e897-b414-4faf-892c-ffd415f4d451" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="30eff523-5ebc-46f5-9051-2e6604cb772d"
```

Details: FSTAB

```
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1

# /boot was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=aba7016b-3277-416b-9243-fc10f1752b12 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2

# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=BB84-E577  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0


/dev/disk/by-uuid/53c5e897-b414-4faf-892c-ffd415f4d451 /media/steven/data auto nosuid,nodev,nofail 0 0
```

Comment: Which group owns the HDD, add www-data to that group.

Comment: run `ls -ald /path/to/hdd` to find the group that owns that device!

Comment: `ls -ald /dev/sdb2` 
results in: 

`brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 18 Dec 21 16:28 /dev/sdb2`

Comment: Add `www-data` to disk group and lets see: `sudo usermod -a -G disk www-data`

Comment: Great let me post an answer then, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things I would suggest:

1. Find which group owns that device:

   ```
   ls -ald /dev/sdX
   ```

   - where `X` is the letter representing the external drive usually `/dev/sdb`, or `/dev/sdc`
2. Add `www-data` user to that group:

   ```
   sudo usermod -a -G disk www-data
   ```

And now user `www-data` should be able to access that external HDD.

Comment: I'll be able to use this answer for a problem I was having with Plex Media Server too (changing www-data to plex). Thanks George.